# hide Canvas depending on child's content

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

this is my latest try to make the canvas Invisible whenever the label.Content is an empty String. Any help/advice appreciated, thanks.

```
<Canvas Visibility="Visible">
    <Label Content="" Name="holamouse" />
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=holamouse, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: When the binding is correct, is there a solution for a value "string.isnullorempty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that a local property value always has higher precedence than a value set by a Style Setter. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

When you set `Visibility="Visible"` on the Canvas, any Style Setter for that property is silently ignored. You could move the property assignment to the Style, although `Visible` is the default value anyway:

```
<Canvas>
    <Label Content="" Name="holamouse" />
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=holamouse}"
                             Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, ElementName=holamouse}"
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

Please note also that there is a second trigger for `Value="{x:Null}"` now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the default Visibility property out of the `<Canvas>` tag and into the `<Style>`

This is because properties defined in the `<Tag>` take precedence over any property setters, including triggered property setters. See MSDN's [Dependency Property Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) if you want more details.

```
<Canvas>
    <Label Content="" Name="holamouse" />
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, ElementName=holamouse, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: right!, i remember i added the setter unter style.triggers and it wont compile, so i removed it again. ty 4 post